# Excel to XML conversion using XSD Schema in Python

Tags: python, xml, excel, xsd

This is my very first question to the group. 
I am trying to Generate XML file from an Excel file by using XSD Schema file. I already have the XSD schema file (which is of nested type) and mapped the same manually to Excel file and by clicking export button I am able to retrieve the XML file. Below is a youtube video for the steps which I've referred:-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klbi56fW0k4

But, I want the same to be worked with Python now.

I've tried the below piece of code:-

`

```
import xlrd
file = 'file.xlsx'       #file on my local desktop
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

table = list ()
record = list ()

for x in range(sheet.nrows):
    for y in range(sheet.ncols):
        record.append(sheet.cell_value(x, y))
    table.append(record)
    record = []
    x += 1

print (table) #this list is flat , not sure how to convert it to nested using XSD template file
```

`

You can find the relevant documents (Excel, XSD and output XML) below:-
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gQexndq6Lb7s1j5jpg-hcDKT5fIFM1i3?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance.
Regards
Nitin

Comment: Please read the help file for StackOverflow. In particular, you should make your own attempt to write code for this task and then, if you encounter difficulties, bring specific questions here for possible answers.

Comment: I believe this question is very specific that I want to utilize XSD files in EXCEL to create XML. I have tried using the xlrd module, but not able to find any documentation related to this context in particular. It would be great if you can answer or share some link in this regards.

Comment: Questions on SO should be self-contained as far as possible, and should not require potential respondents to visit other sites. Furthermore, you have not included any code of your own.

Comment: import xlrd
file = 'file.xlsx'  #File name on my local desktop machine
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

table = list ()
record = list ()

for x in range(sheet.nrows):
    for y in range(sheet.ncols):
        record.append(sheet.cell_value(x, y))
    table.append(record)
    record = []
    x += 1

print (table)


#Script for converting dictionary to XML
xml = dicttoxml(table , custom_root='expense', attr_type=False)
print(xml)

Above is the code which I tried at my end, but it is giving a flat array not a hierarchical(nested) dict.

Comment: This should go into your question.

Comment: done.. added...